# Trouble freeing memory using a multiply linked tree

Tags: c++

I have a tree where each node has six children nodes and also a pointer to it's parent node. The struct looks like this:

```
struct node
{
  float value;
  int wins;
  int games;
  int visited;
  int colour;

  node *prev;

  node *p[6];
};
```

The root node is initialized as such:

```
root = new node;
root -> value   = 0.0;
root -> wins    = 0;
root -> games   = 0;
root -> visited = 0;
root -> colour  = c; //root node has same colour as opponent

root -> prev = NULL; //can use this to find root.

for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
  root -> p[i] = NULL;
```

And the expansion function looks like this:

```
void expansion(int column, node *leaf)
{
  node *child = new node;
  child -> value   = 0.0;
  child -> wins    = 0;
  child -> games   = 0;
  child -> visited = 0;

  if(leaf -> colour == 1)
    child -> colour  = -1;
  else
    child -> colour  = 1;

  child -> prev = leaf;

  for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    child -> p[i] = NULL;

  leaf -> p[column] = child;
}
```

I think my main problem is in my function to free the memory which looks like this:

```
void destroy_tree(node *leaf)
{
  if(leaf!=NULL)
  {
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
      destroy_tree(leaf->p[i]);

    delete leaf -> prev;
    delete leaf; 
  }
}
```

Essentially I tried to expand a function to delete a binary tree to my function where I need to delete all six children.

Comment: You have yet to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: ... and a [MCVE] would help as well.

Comment: `delete leaf -> prev;` That doesn't seem right. Why are you deleting the previous node as well?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm getting memory leaks when I run it through Valgrind.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit When I call `delete leaf -> prev;` does that delete the pointer to the previous node or delete the previous node?

Comment: @JohnMeighan you cannot delete a pointer, you only can delete the thing pointed by a pointer. Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: @JohnMeighan: It triggers destruction of the dynamically-allocated thing that the pointer is pointing to. Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: you can check how destroy_tree works with pen and paper on simple exmple step by step. You will see that you try to dereference pointer after deleting object it points to. (it caused by delete leaf->prev)

Comment: @MichaelWalz OK I'll try that, my full code is much longer I'll see how much I can cut it down.

Comment: @JohnMeighan what happens if you simply drop `delete leaf -> prev;`?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I tried that there, it is definitely helping, I think I still have some other bugs to work out but that's better.

Comment: @JohnMeighan the diagnostic by valgrind could be caused by previous undefined behaviour, for example deleting the same object twice.

Answer (score 2):

> `delete leaf -> prev;` That doesn't seem right. Why are you deleting the previous node as well? *– Lightness Races in Orbit*

True - imagine what happens with only two nodes, `root` and `root->p[0]`:

```
destroy_tree(root)
{
    destroy_tree(p[0])
    {
        delete leaf->prev; // which is root!
        delete leaf;
     }
     delete leaf->prev; // nullptr anyway (*)
     delete leaf;  //// root; ALREADY deleted!!! ////
}
```

(*) `prev` *would* have been a null pointer - if it existed yet! But as you deleted `leaf` (aka root here) already, you are actually dereferencing a dangling pointer (undefined behaviour)! And immediately afterwards, you try to delete via exactly this dangling pointer – again undefined behaviour...

valgrind is a really good, but not perfect tool. It discovered that you apparently are not deleting the object pointed at by a pointer (`prev`), which it spotted as *potential* memory leak. Obviously, it was not aware that the `prev` pointer's object was yet reachable via another pointer...

Answer (score 1):

imagine you have node LP with two child nodes LC1, LC2 :

LP->p[0] == LC1,

LP->p[1] == LC2,

LC1->prev == LP,

LC2->prev == LP

then call

```
destroy_tree(LP)
```

unwinds into

```
destroy_tree(LP)
destroy_tree(LP->p[0])
delete LC1->prev 
delete LC1
destroy_tree(LP->p[1]) // but at this point LP is already deleted
delete LC2->prev // but at this point LP is already deleted
delete LC2
delete LP->prev // at his point LP is already deleted 
delete LP  // at this point LP is already deleted
```